# Error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while redirecting on Action Filter onActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue in redirecting to the external URL
**Requirement** I want to redirect to an external URL whenever the session is expired.

I have a separate class in which I override the definition of onActionExecuting Action

Here is my Code:

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       // var redirectUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        var isAjaxRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();

        if (isAjaxRequest)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
}
```

I Have try almost all the solution that I could find on Stack Over Flow but my problem is not still solved.

Is there is any issue related to pipeline execution of controller filters if so kindly guide me.

Note on console its shows this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49815' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**Edited**

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var redirectUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        var isAjaxRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();

        if (isAjaxRequest)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "TestController" }, { "action", "Redirect" } });
            if (filterContext.Result!=null)
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

And This is my Controller & Action

```
 public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why on earth would you redirect an ajax request to an external Url when sessions expires? Isn't it a better way to send 401 status code and unauthorized response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are doing an `XMLHttpRequest` to a different domain than your page is on. You are getting the error because of [same origin for security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Consider using this [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

[Also consider Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is a W3C spec that allows cross-domain communication from the browser. By building on top of the XMLHttpRequest object, CORS allows developers to work with the same idioms as same-domain requests

**EDIT:**

As per OP's comment adding this. You redirect to controller action method like below :

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                    {{"controller", "Home"}, {"action", "Index"}});
```

Comment: thanks for guidance can u guide me further how to resolve this issue

Comment: I also try to navigate controller action but failed to do so... you are saying right but why it doesn't work for Controller action ...

Comment: it does not allow us to redirect internally

       filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");

Comment: it does not allow us to redirect internally (Action/Controller).In separate class it does not allow me to define object of RedirectToAction and neither show any namespace to resolve it ...

Comment: i implemnet your second solution it doesn't show an error but still not Redirect to controller action

Comment: @SaadAfzal You are not understanding my point. Again you are doing cross domain request in action method. Because of this only I gave you some other ways to achieve your requirement. Please read carefully my answer from start and follow the solution.

Comment: Thanks Rahul your solution redirects me to the internal action but the thing is from controller action am trying to redirect to external URL now still having same issue ... from there too

Comment: @SaadAfzal What are you expecting is cross domain request which is not allowed by default. Please follow links from my solution to achieve your requirement.